# Vuetify - when checkbox is bind to a null value, it can only single select

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

---

### Example

```
<v-checkbox v-for="(v,k) in questionContent.choices" :key="k"
    v-model="answerData[question.id]" @change="saveAnswer(qe.id, question.id)"
    :label="`${k}. ${v}`"
    :value="k"
    hide-details
```

About this value specified in `v-model`:

- If it's `null` initially, then only one checkbox can be checked at a time.
- If it's `[]` *(empty array)* initially, then multiple checkboxes can be checked at once.

---

### The problem is

The initial data is load from database, which is better be `null` *(actually the sub property for the `question.id` doesn't exists initially, it's stored within a `jsonb` column of `postgresql`)*.

If I have to initialize the value to `[]`, it will increase the complexity & fragility of the data, *(e.g it might be harder to do data migration, and introduce bugs later)*.

---

### Questions

- Is it possible to make the `<v-checkbox>` support multiple selection when the initial value of `v-model` is null ?

Comment: do you mean that *`answerData[question.id]`* could be null initially ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, `answerData` is an object, and not null, but `answerData[question.id]` could be null initially.

Comment: and you want to convert the null value to an empty array?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim No, I hope the `<v-checkbox>` behavior identically no matter the value is null or empty array. Currently it's not, check the question for details.